# React native align image with text

Tags: css, image, react-native, user-interface, flexbox

on react native i already wrap the image with tag View. the code is below

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 3, alignItems:'center' }}>
     <Image source={Images.rank} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}></Image>
     <Text style={[mainstyle.textGrey, mainstyle.fs14, mainstyle.ml5,]}>
         {I18n.t('Rank')}: 
         <Text onPress={() => this._goto('Rank')} 
             style={[mainstyle.textRed, mainstyle.fs14, mainstyle.bold, 
                 mainstyle.textUnderline]}>
                     {this.state.monthRank == '' ? 
                         '-' : this.state.monthRank}
         </Text>
      </Text> 
</View>
```

how i put the text on the center the container and align center with the image to. as we can see the text slightly up
[image: image not align well with text]

Comment: Could you reproduce this behavior in [codepen?](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gwoJZk)